# What is the best way to keep files in sync between an EC2 instance and a local Win Machine?

Tags: amazon-ec2, database, python, synchronization

Premise: I'm a complete newb. So any gentle hints are much appreciated :)

So, I spun up an EC2 instance and dumped my scraper I had built in Python. I've set up cronjobs to run my scraper at scheduled intervals. At each run, my scraper saves a set of results to a relative local folder such as (`db//db1.csv`, `db//db2.csv`, etc). Say, the state of these DB files is quite important as they are then used as the source to compile API calls and maintain a website.

I would like to run my scraper from my local machine too, for testing purposes. So, I'm trying to figure out, whenever I'm running my scraper locally, how to ensure I have the latest state of DB files I can build on -- effectively writing a function to download the latest DB files from my EC2 instance.

I've been experimenting with `scp -i` parameters in my `cmd` console, and this works fine, as I'm able to retrieve my files. But, I'm having troubles wrapping these commands in Python using `os` or `subprocess`, and either run the command directly or run a batch file with these commands.

It seems Python is locked inside my virtual environment, and cannot find `ssh.exe` within my `C:/windows/system32/OpenSSH`. I could not solve this, so realized from StackOverflow threads, that most users use the `paramiko` library to SSH directly into their EC2 instance.

Right now, I feel I'm over-complicating my workflows, having to SSH-download files to keep states aligned between a remote and my localhost. I'm looking to migrate all my DBs to PostgreSQL on AWS RDS and manage everything this way. I'm curious to hear ideas (based on any assumptions), and what's the best architecture going forward so that:

1. I can run my scraper from a remote host and schedule its runs with cronjob, automating the broadcast of fresh data to a website
2. But also, work on a new code version locally, without breaking my remote DB states

What am I missing? I'm more interested in ideas to solve this, than actual code. Thanks!

Comment: What is the virtual environment you are running Python in? Do you run Python in a VM? Then install ssh on this VM also. If you are unable to connect with SSH, you can also put these files (by script) into some password-protected area of your website, and download them over HTTP(S) right from Python.

Comment: Thanks Raj. Running Python in virtualenv not VM. Going to try to install ssh in there. Did not think of using a password-protected area of the website as a repo! Will try this too!

Comment: Lots of ways though: use `boto3` to upload your CSVs to S3 then pull your CSVs in your client using `boto3` or `requests` if you set it as public; enable `sftp` on your EC2 instance then pull files with `sftp.exe` command; or maybe install [WSL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10#manual-installation-steps) and use Linux on your Windows 10 instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split it into two independent tasks:

1. Keep the files in sync
2. Run your scraper locally without worrying about the sync (assuming the #1 does its job)

For keeping the files in sync I would use [**Syncthing**](https://syncthing.net/) - I use it to sync files between my laptops and to EC2 as a backup. It runs all the time and whenever it can connect it does the sync. Works on Linux, Windows, Mac.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense. Going to experiment with Syncthing! :)